# Using components instead controllers in EmberJS v2

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am beginner in EmberJS. I have made [todomvc for ember v2](https://github.com/izumeroot/ember2-todomvc) for learning Ember.

My implementation works without controller. I use components instead controllers.

In the [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/controllers/) I see:

> Controllers are very much like components, so much so that in future versions of Ember, controllers will be replaced entirely with components.

But I think it is some ugly solution. Now I will explain why.

This is template for the todo item component for my todolist
app/templates/components/todo-item.hbs:

```
<li class="{{if isCompleted 'completed'}} {{if isEditing 'editing'}}">
    {{#if isEditing}}
        {{input-focused class="edit" value=item.title focus-out="acceptChanges" insert-newline="acceptChanges"}}
    {{else}}
      {{input type="checkbox" checked=isCompleted class="toggle"}}
      <label {{action "editTodo" on="doubleClick"}}>{{item.title}}</label><button {{action "removeTodo"}} class="destroy"></button>
    {{/if}}
</li>
```

It has `acceptChanges` and `removeTodo` events. And in the JS part of component I have handlers:

```
//app/components/todo-item.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    updateTodoAction: 'updateTodo',
    deleteTodoAction: 'deleteTodo',

    isEditing: false,

    // some lines removed for brevity

    actions: {
      editTodo: function() {
        this.set('isEditing', true);
      },

      acceptChanges: function() {
        this.set('isEditing', false);
        this.sendAction('updateTodoAction', this.get('item'), this.get('item.title'));
      },

      removeTodo: function () {
        this.sendAction('deleteTodoAction', this.get('item'));
      }
    }
});
```

In the JS code of component I don't work with storage. I send `this.sendAction()`, and my route will handle it. And todos-route works with storage.

Please look at todos route:

```
// app/routes/todos.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('todo');
    },

    actions: {
        // some lines removed from here for brevity

        updateTodo: function(todo, title) {
            if (Ember.isEmpty(title)) {
                this.send('deleteTodo', todo);
            } else {
                todo.save();
            }
        },

        deleteTodo: function(todo) {
            todo.deleteRecord();
            todo.save();
        },

       // some lines removed from here for brevity
    }
});
```

When the user clicks on the remove button, it generates `removeTodo` action and it will handled in `removeTodo()` in the JS part of the component. And then the `removeTodo()` function calls  `this.sendAction('deleteTodoAction' ... )`, which generates `deleteTodo` action. This action will handled in todos route in  `deleteTodo()` method. I have `todo.save()` in this method.

The `acceptChanges` action works much like `removeTodo`, but it sets the property `isEditing = false` before calling `this.sendAction`.

I have following chain for actions:

```
component template -> component js -> route
```

I think for `deleteTodo()`, it will be better to exclude the component JS part. But how?

In `updateTodo()` I need the component JS part, because I set the value for the `isEditing` property. But for calling route, I need the `updateTodoAction` property. And it is ugly for me. Can it work without the `updateTodoAction` property? How?

Also, I'd like to see any your comments about my solution (components instead controllers) or any part of my code.